# Окончание существительных в предложении

Tags: падежи

Здравствуйте! Встретила следующий текст:

> "Проработаны вопросы дооборудования противопожарных полос на расстояние 500 метров от административных зданий".

Правильное ли окончание "на расстояние" или "на расстоянии". Если предложение построить таким образом:

> "Проработаны вопросы дооборудования противопожарных полос вокруг административных зданий на расстояние 300 метров".

Изменится ли окончание?

Answer (score 2):

Варианты:

Начать оборудовать с пятисотого метра и дальше — **на расстоянии** 500 м.   Дооборудовать до необходимых пятисот метров — **на расстояние** 500 м.

Answer (score 1):

Не изменится окончание. Оно от количества метров не зависит. А зависит от падежа. В данном случае падеж винительный. Следовательно, окончание Е: *дооборудование  на расстояние 500 метров*

Comment: в каком случае будет окончание -и? Сможете привести наглядный пример

Answer (score 1):

Нет, неправильно. Дооборудование противопожарных полос, как правило, производится при изменении норматива расстояния от объектов, который эти полосы должны защищать от пожарной опасности, и заключается в расчистке территории от деревьев, кустарников, сухой травы и прочих потенциально горючих материалов, размещении дополнительных пожарных водоёмов, гидрантов, противопожарных щитов и пр. Поэтому "на расстояние", а не "на расстоянии": не в пятистах метрах от зданий расчищать кустарник, а от нуля до пятисот метров от зданий всё вырубить, спилить, скосить и вывезти. Не "вокруг зданий", а именно "от зданий", т. е. расстояние измеряется от стен по вектору пожароопасного направления, а не по кругу.

Это не ошибка и не трижды клятый канцелярит - эти формулировки очень дорого стоят. Иногда жизней стоят.

Comment: mueller, так я тоже ответил, что это винительный падеж. Что у вас вызвало сомнение моем ответе?

Comment: Вот же засада. Да, конечно, винительный. Верно вы сказали. Только перепутали, что прорабатывается, а что дооборудуется )))

Comment: Да, с терминологией перепутал.

Answer (score 0):

Проработаны на что ?- на расстояние.Следовательно, здесь винительный падеж. Т.е. полосы проработаны на определенное расстояние, длина полосы равна 500метрам.  Если поставить предложный падеж, изменится смысл предложения: вопросы прорабатывались, находясь на расстоянии 500 метров, т.е. вдалеке от административных зданий; что не совсем корректно в данном предложении.

Comment: Кхе. Проработаны - вопросы. Полосы - дооборудованы. Будут. Может быть.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Серж, вы пишете: 
оработаны на что ?- на расстояние.Следовательно, здесь винительный падеж. Т.е. полосы проработаны на определенное расстояние, длина полосы равна 500метрам"

Comment: У вас есть варианты?

Comment: Серж, гляньте на исходный текст. Проработано что? А вариант я написал уже.

Answer (score 0):

У непосвящённого могут возникнуть такие вопросы:

В чем заключается дооборудование: в оборудовании дополнительных полос на указанном расстоянии? Тогда "на расстояни**и**" и нужно прямым текстом так и сказать. Или оно состоит в переносе существующих полос на другое расстояние (500 метров)? Тогда перенос происходит "на расстояни**е**" и это уже "**пере**оборудование" на другое расстояни**е**. Здесь тоже лучше сказать о "переносе" прямо: трудно представить себе, чтобы в результате "дооборудования" (или переоборудования) дооборудованное оказалось на другом расстоянии от первоначального места оборудования.

Comment: Думаю Вы правы, и в тексте просто допущена ошибка. Правильно всё-таки окончание -и.